# using comparator i achieved to get this data

Tags: ios, objective-c

Data are
...
...
...

Event name :- HSS WE 
Date :-  6/10/2016 - 7/10/2016

Event name :-  CSS Retreat
Date :- 6/10/2016 - 9/10/2016

Event name :- Digital Public Conference
Date :- 6 October 2016 - 7 October 2016

Event name :- GEO Conference
Date :-  6/10/2016 - 7/10/2016

Event name :- ISB Conference
Date :- 6 October 2016 - 7 October 2016
...
...
... etc

I have sorted this using time Stamp, But now as I have same date, I want to sort this data with event name Ascending without affecting other datas in my array.

Comment: show your code, show event contained array here.

Comment: How did you sort? You can specify various keys to sort, or if you used a comparator block, if the date is the same, you can sort by name.

Comment: NSComparisonResult dateEvent1SortDescending(EventInfo *event1, EventInfo *event2, void *context) {
    
    
    
    return [event2.eventStartDateStamp compare:event1.eventStartDateStamp]; 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have this class:

```
@interface EventInfo
//Note that calling a NSDate with timeStamp is weird, we may expect a NSTimerInverval
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate eventStartTimeStamp; 
@proprety (nonatomic, strong) NSDate eventName;
@end
```

You use a `NSComparisonResult` block.
Instead of simply return the comparison of the dates, if is the date is the same, return then the comparison (alphabetical) with the event name.

```
NSMutableArray *array = //Your array of EventInfo objects;
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(EventInfo * _Nonnull event1, EventInfo * _Nonnull event2) {
    NSComparisonResult dateCompare = [event2.eventStartDateStamp compare:event1.eventStartDateStamp]; 
    /*Date are not the same => Date comparison is priority*/
    if (dateCompare != NSOrderedSame)
    {
       return dateCompare;
    }
    else/*Same date => Use Event name to sort*/
    {
        return [event2.eventName compare:event1.eventName];
        //or return [event1.eventName compare:event2.eventName]; depending on alphabetical or reversed 
    }
}];
```

Comment: Event name :- HSS WE Date :- 6/10/2016 - 7/10/2016 
This is still in same place.. 
It should come after
 Event name :- GEO Conference Date :- 6/10/2016 - 7/10/2016

Comment: `return [event1.eventName compare:event2.eventName]` may be better? And I mismatch the method (`sortedArray...` and `sortUsing...`, one applied on the same mutable array, the other one return the sorted array.

Comment: Getting an error.. " No visibility @interface for NSArray declare the selector 'sortUsingComparator"

Comment: If's for the mutable version. Nevermind. Do has you did before, just replace the line with thre NScomparisonResult